# ItextSharp unclosed tag

Tags: html, itext

I'm getting an error in this line:

```
xmlParser.Parse(new StringReader(strHtml));
```

> Invalid nested tag tr found, expected closing tag td.

but when I validate my html file it is ok.

My file exceeds the 30,000 limit, is this the cause?

Comment: Why not start trying with a shorter correct example, then making the example not correct? THEN try a more complex example...

Comment: 30000 character limit? What are you using to validate the html?

Answer (score 0):

My HTML was bad formated but in a validator online dont show the error so i have to validate tag by tag to find the error